# Generate accurate concave hull for data sets in R

Tags: r, concave-hull

I was trying to generate the concave hull of my data set using concaveman function.
Here is my data: 
[image: 1]

According to the shape, I would expect the concave hull looks like a band.
However, after I run code:

```
Sec_poly <- as.data.frame(concave_hull(as.matrix(Sec_Coords[,1:2]), concavity = 2, length_threshold = 0))
```

Result looks like:
[image]
The inner details were wiped out by the algorithm. 
I also tried to adjust the concavity,
[image] 
Now the ring appeared but also a weird triangle polygon. Is there any method to solve this?

What I want is the shape (roughly):

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you expect it to look like a band? Can you draw what you expect? Can you supply you data to us? Can you say what you changed to produce the second picture?

Comment: If you had a closed geometry, you wouldn't give the algorithm fits.

Comment: @Spacedman I edited the question, the band looks like the shape in the picture. And I edited the concavity to get the second picture

Comment: Maybe alpha shapes will fit for your problem?  [https://www.r-bloggers.com/alpha-shapes-with-r-and-lattice/]